# PHP: Parse Web API response in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I have to consume an old Web API in Laravel.

Response body looks like this:

```
TRANSACTION_ID: KJASDFYDSF^SDFHJSD/2236
STATUS: OK
DATE: 01/03/18
```

How can I convert the response into Array using Guzzle 6?

Comment: Why would you parse it into JSON?

Comment: Don't convert the response into JSON, just parse the response in that format. Converting to JSON would anyway require you to parse the response first, so why add the extra - useless - step?

Comment: I need to get the TRANSACTION_ID, STATUS and other properties from the response. Is it possible to do this automatically with Guzzle or I need to parse them with Regex?

Comment: you have to parse them manually. The given format is not a standard. Usually its being sent as JSON/xml/querystring but this you'll have to parse manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution with parsing response:

```
private function parseResponse(\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $response) {
    $body = $response->getBody();
    $body->rewind();
    $content = (string) $body->getContents();
    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $content);
    $result = [];

    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $chunks = explode(':', $line);
        $result[trim($chunks[0])] = trim($chunks[1]);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Also it's better to call `explode()` with the third, `$limit` parameter: `$chunks = explode(':', $line, 2);`